# Specify methods for use in index creation

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis, jooq

Using PostGIS, you may create an index with the following;

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_gix
ON mytable
USING GIST (myCol);
```

Using JOOQ, I have access to methods such as `createIndexIfNotExists`

How can I maintain the method usage `USING GIST` with something like;

```
dslContext
.createIndexIfNotExists("table_gix")
.on("table")
.execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.13, this syntax is not supported in the DSL API yet. You'll have to roll your own, using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/):

```java
dslContext.execute("create index mytable_gix on mytable using gist (mycol)");
```

If you have generated objects from your schema that you'd like to reuse, use the templating features:

```java
dslContext.execute(
  "create index {0} on {1} using gist ({2})", 
  name("mytable_gix"),
  MYTABLE,
  MYTABLE.MYCOL.getUnqualifiedName()
);
```